# glFenceSync alternative in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: opengl-es, synchronization, opengl-es-2.0, gpu

I see that `glFenceSync` does not exist in OpenGL ES 2.0, it was added only in OpenGL ES 3.0.

Does OpenGL ES 2.0 offer any alternative of syncing between CPU and GPU, aside from the brutal force `glFinish`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `glext.h`.

```
GL_API GLsync glFenceSyncAPPLE(GLenum condition, GLbitfield flags) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_6_0);
```

I am pretty sure this is what you want. Anyway available only on iOS 6.0 or later.

Answer (score 2):

You have different calls in OpenGL ES 2.0 that give some insight into different matters concerning GL, but mainly, you're left with `glFinish` only.

Comment: Thank you, but what do you mean by 'insight into different matters concerning GL'? Is there a way to tell whether the GPU has completed a specific task, without having to wait until it has completed **all** tasks?

Comment: I was talking about all the `glGet...` methods that use can use to inquire different variables, but you're pretty much left out when trying to inquire if different tasks are done.